# Будет ли работать отправка формы обратной связи через ajax на почту на локальном сервере?

Tags: ajax, modx, openserver

Я делаю форму обратной связи на ajax, мне интересно будут ли приходить письма если я развернул свой сайт на modx на OpenServer?

Comment: Будут. Если всё верно настроить.

Comment: В кач-ве smtp сервера пропишите [Mailtrap](https://help.mailtrap.io/article/5-smtp-integration) и будете получать почту

Comment: Не имеет значения где какой сайт, имеет значение где какой почтовый сервер и правильно ли он настроен